# How to solve this limit? $(1+x)^{\frac{y}{x}}$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to solve this limit?

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)} (1+x)^{\frac{y}{x}}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the limit definition for [$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations)?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,0)}(1+x)^{\frac{y}{x}}= \lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{2}{x}}= \lim_{z\to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1 z\right)^{2z} = e^2$$